# How do I recursively get the size of a Linked List?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to find the size of a linked list using recursive algorithm. Here is what I have so far:

```
  public int getCurrentSize()
  {
     int size = 0;

     size = getCurrentSizeHelper(headRef);

     return size;
  }


  public int getCurrentSizeHelper(BoxClass workingRef)
  {
     int sizeAtIndex = 0;

     //If empty, size is zero
     if (isEmpty())
        {
           return sizeAtIndex;
        }

     //If there is no next box, end recursion and increment size
     if (workingRef.nextRef == null)
        {
           sizeAtIndex++;
        }

     //While there are next boxes, increment size and continue recursion
     else
        {
           sizeAtIndex = getCurrentSizeHelper(workingRef.nextRef) + 1;
        }

     return sizeAtIndex;
  }
```

I had this working earlier, however, every time I try to run it I get a stack overflow error. Would appreciate any insight into this problem.

Comment: What's the stack trace? Is `isEmpty` calling `getCurrentSize`?

Comment: It looks like you've built a cyclic list.

Comment: the task of determining of the length of a linked list is linear, not recursive.

Comment: I know that it is a linear process, but for this assignment we were supposed to do it recursively. `isEmpty` simply checks to see if the head reference is equal to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better compact version (pseudo code):

```
  public int getCurrentSizeHelper(BoxClass workingRef)
  {
       if (workingRef.isEmpty())
       {
           return 0;
       }
       return getCurrentSizeHelper(workingRef.nextRef) + 1;
  }
```

This will do the work. Take any example and work it out and check yourself.